# Exact and approximate agorithms for independent set probem in large graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, approximation

I have a problem which could be stated as follows:

Given an unweighted undirected graph $G=(V, E)$ and positive integer $k \leq |V|$, I need to find a subset of vertices $R \subseteq V$ such that $|R| \geq k$ and no two vertices in $R$ are joined by an edge in $E$.

As you can see, this is the definition of the independent set problem for an unweighted undirected graph. (Although not the decision version of the problem.)

Now, I was wondering if someone could provide me with some help on:

1. finding the (optimal) independent set (ie, $R$) of size $k$ in case it exists on a graph when $|V|<10^5$ and $|E|<10^6$?
2. Find an approximation of the optimal solution for a possibly very large graph (ie, millions of vertices and billions of edges)?

Simply put, my question is, what the exact and approximate algorithms that work well for finding the independent set on a very large graph?

I very much appreciate your answers and suggestions.

Hassan

Comment: The answer to 1 is probably no unless you have some insight into the structure of your graph, like bounded treewidth or degeneracy. Same for 2, you probably need to rely on randomised or heuristic algorithms.